# Display text in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am just starting to learn D3 and currently working through understanding [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

I am trying to get text to display next to each node in the graph. In the JSON data, there is a key named `name`, which contains the name of a character from Les Misérables. I am trying to display this text next to each node using this code:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill", "black")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name;}).style("font-family", "Arial").style("font-size", 12)
        .call(force.drag);
```

I've basically just altered the `.text` to try and display text. Can anyone explain how I can get text to display? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The SVG `<circle>` element will not display any text that you place inside it using the `.text` function. A way to display the text would be to make the nodes of the graph SVG `<g>` elements. These can then contain a `<circle>` and a `<text>` child elements.

This could look like this :

```
\\create graph nodes using groups
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("g").call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 5)
.style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); });

node.append("text")
.text(function (d) { return d.name; });
```

You would also need to change the force so that it transforms the group `<g>` on a tick.

```
force.on("tick", function () {
...
node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});
```

You can see it in action for a small graph at http://jsfiddle.net/vrWDc/19/. This method may not be very efficient when applied to a large graph due to the amount of text that needs to be rendered.

Comment: An easy and understandable explanation. It helps me too. Thank you